# array_diff() removing partial values

Tags: php, arrays

I am developing a hashtag search system on Instagram. And I get a list of users with their posts in the following form:

```
username1-idposts123455665435, username2-idposts45634563456, username3-idposts276544234....
```

I set up an array to be able to work with the display on my page, with the code, where `$getRelatorio` are the users above.

```
$base_array_split = preg_split("/,\s/", $getRelatorio);
    $base_array_filtro = array_filter($base_array_split);

    foreach($base_array_filtro as $explode_usuarios_array)
    {
        $explode_usuarios = explode("-", $explode_usuarios_array);
        
        $array1[] = array(
            $explode_usuarios[0], //get username
            $explode_usuarios[1] // ger post id
        );
    }
```

Everything works fine. But I want to implement a Black List system, to block the display of users that the customer does not want to see.

I store it in the database in the same way, separated by a comm and to work, I also assemble an array.

```
$base_array_lista = preg_split("/,\s/", $listanegra);
    $base_array_filtro_lista = array_filter($base_array_lista);

    foreach($base_array_filtro_lista as $explode_lista_negra)
    {
        $is_array[] = array(
            $explode_lista_negra //get username
        );
    }

$array2 = isset($is_array) && is_array($is_array) ? $is_array : []; //if empty
```

Now, I am using the following to exclude the users that the customer has blacklisted:

```
$arrayfinal = array();

foreach($array1 as $arr)
{
    $arrayfinal[] = array_diff($arr, array_column($array2, 0));
}

$array = array_filter($arrayfinal);
```

The difference between the two arrays is that one has the post id.

The result:
I am able to remove the username, but the post ID is still displayed in the array.

If i remove `array_column($array2, 0)` it doesn't work.
If i use `array_diff_assoc` it doesn't work either

var_dump:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => username1
            [1] => 2577195852001190087
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => username2
            [1] => 2577195809822230254
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2577195306530472731 //username removed, bud post id is not - need to remove that too
        )
```

var_dump expected:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => username1
            [1] => 2577195852001190087
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => username2
            [1] => 2577195809822230254
        )
```

Comment: What does the blacklist consist of? Only usernames? If so, `array_diff` is doing its job and is not the right tool here. What you need to do is a plain comparison of usernames - if they match you don't add it to the result.

Comment: Is either username or postid unique in the array?

Comment: Yes, the blacklist consists of username only.  How would this simple comparison be? With if?

Comment: All values ​​are unique. Both username and post id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index on `username` or `postid` and do it like this (indexed on postid):

```
foreach(explode(', ', $string) as $values) {
    $parts = explode('-idposts', $values);
    $result[$parts[1]] = $parts[0];
}
$blacklist = ['username3'];
$result = array_diff($result, $blacklist);
```

Or using the format you have:

```
foreach(explode(', ', $string) as $values) {
    $parts = explode('-idposts', $values);
    $result[$parts[0]] = $parts;
}
$blacklist = ['username3'];
$result = array_diff_key($result, array_flip($blacklist));
```

Comment: But what if I need to blacklist multiple users? In the example, which, by the way, works perfectly, thank you for that, how would my `$blacklist` look?

Comment: It's an array, you get it from somewhere but `$blacklist = ['username2', 'username3'];`

Comment: if black list thats empty, i have the error: Uninitialized string offset 0. i am not able to solve with isset().

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way.. flatten the arrays using json_encode, comparing then reinflating.
View a demo here:
https://www.tehplayground.com/IcpKbUyFltbXhNQp

```
<?php

$array1 = array(
    array("username1", "2577195852001190087"),
    array("username2", "1577195852001190087"),
    array("username3", "3577195852001190087")
    );
$array2 = array(
    array("username2", "1577195852001190087"),
    array("username3", "3577195852001190087")
    );

$a=array_map(function($v) { return json_encode($v); }, $array1);
$b=array_map(function($v) { return json_encode($v); }, $array2);
$arrayfinal = array_map(function($v) { return json_decode($v); }, array_diff($a, $b) );


$array = array_filter($arrayfinal);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in $array2 i don't have the id values.